# Why does java use an oblique font when asking for a plain monospaced font?

Tags: java, fonts, embedded-linux

I create a monospaced font in my application with :

```
Font f = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 18);
```

When I run the application on a PC, the font looks fine (`Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Java SE Runtime Environment - build 1.7.0_25-b15`).

When I run the application on an ARM computer, the font is slanted to the right (`Debian Squeeze, armel, Java SE Embedded Runtime Environment - build 1.7.0_10-b18`).

I tested this small program :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setTerminalFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 18));
        setTerminalFont(new Font("DejaVu Sans Mono", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    }
    private static void setTerminalFont(Font x_font) {
        System.out.println("Font family=["+x_font.getFamily()+"] name=["+x_font.getFontName()+"] i-angle="+x_font.getItalicAngle());        
    }
}
```

On the PC computer, it prints:

```
Font family=[Monospaced] name=[Monospaced.plain] i-angle=0.0
Font family=[DejaVu Sans Mono] name=[DejaVu Sans Mono] i-angle=0.0
```

On the ARM computer, it prints:

```
Font family=[Monospaced] name=[Monospaced.plain] i-angle=0.1899996
Font family=[DejaVu Sans Mono] name=[DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique] i-angle=0.1899996
```

Can someone explain why the ARM version uses *DejaVu Sans Mono **Oblique*** ?

How can I make java to use the plain *DejaVu Sans Mono* font instead of an oblique one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the *plain* `Font.MONOSPACED` logical font is buggy on my system, my solution was to list all the fonts available on my system with :

```
System.out.println("Listing available fonts");
for (Font f : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts())
   System.out.println("- "+f);
```

And trying the mono-ones and typewriter-ones that claims to be *plain* or *regular* or anything that is not oblique until I found one that is really *plain*.

I ended up with `Lucida Sans Typewriter Regular`.